# aufs mount fails on root partition in ubuntu

Tags: mount

I have been trying to execute the following command in teminal on ubuntu.

```
sudo mount -t aufs -o br:/tmp/update/copy=rw:/=ro none /
```

copy folder contains file x but after after mount i donot see the contrnets from /tmp/update/copy in /. but the contents of / are present in /. one more thing is that when i try the following command:

```
sudo mount -t aufs -o br:/tmp/update/copy=rw none /
```

the contents still dont change. can anyone tell me a solution to this problem or a work around that would help me mount my stuff from other folder in /.
but if i try the following command it works perfectly the contents of both folders are visible

```
sudo mount -t aufs -o br:/tmp/update/copy=rw:/mnt=ro none /mnt
```

mount returns 0 in all cases which means that mount was a success and it can also be seen in mount command

```
none on / type aufs (rw,br:/tmp/update/copy:/)
```

but mounted files are absent.

Comment: Should the syntax not be `sudo mount -t aufs -o br=/First_dir:/second_dir none /path` ?

Comment: i have tried that it doesnt work either and interestingly mount returns 0. i have tried it without permissions as well the result is still the same

Comment: the latter syntax works with /mnt it just doesnt seem to work with /

Comment: Is that actually a feature rather than a bug then? Doesn't seem a particularly good idea to do this...

Comment: i agree but the idea is to update the root file system without actually putting anything onto it. what I wish to do is to replace some particular binaries in /usr/bin without actually replacing them.

Comment: Try it with just /usr/bin then? What does aufs do with 2 different files of the same name, I've not tried that. Could you not set a ~/bin directory before /usr in $PATH & get the same effect?

Comment: aufs replaces the file of lower priority folder with the file of higher priority. I am designing an update system so in future i might possibly be replacing somthing else somewhere else as well and then it might cause problems for the system. for example if i have some config files in /var/lib or /etc.